# Is there at least one essay focused on Kant's definition of "notions" as intermediary between idea(l)s and conceptions?

Tags: reference-request, kant, concept, knowledge-representation

I tried Googling "Kant 'notions'" but that doesn't seem efficient (from the results I've gotten). I assume that he appealed to the word for its being originally cognate with *noesis* and the like, although whether he used it often, I don't recall, nor whether he always used it in line with his one-off definition of notions as formed by the pure faculty of our concepts (the understanding), with reason forming ideas out of notions.

**Where do notions fit in, exactly, alongside concepts like *type of the law* or *formal intuition*, in Kant's network of kinds of representation?** I doubt they're types as such, since Kant seems to assign types to pure reason, whereas notions have more purchase in the understanding, and they're not formal intuitions of course, but could they be on roughly the same "level of abstraction" as types and formal intuitions?

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to the *Stufenleiter* in CPR:"*A concept is either an empirical or a pure concept, and the pure concept, insofar as it has its origin solely in the understanding (not in a pure image of sensibility), is called notio. A concept made up of notions, which goes beyond the possibility of experience, is an idea or a concept of reason.*" So notions are elementary pure concepts of the understanding that go beyond any possible experience, not formed from concepts. [IEP has a commentary](https://iep.utm.edu/kantmind/#SSH1ai) on them alongside other representations.